# How to move a tab control dynamically on a wpf form

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to move a tab control on a wpf around dynamically.  The tab control is hooked to a timer and basically if you press a button the size is shrunk so it looks and behaves like an expandable panel.  However, when I 'shrink' the tab control the width is adjusted centrally, whereas I want the control to stay where it was positioned in the X axis, how do I do that (why they couldn't do control.location(x,y) I don't know!)?

```
GeneralTransform myTrans = this.tabcontrol1.TransformToAncestor(this);
Point p1 = myTrans.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

I am using the two lines above to get the position, this can be done either via GeneralTransform or visualTreeHelper (which returns a vector) and how do I apply this to the tabcontrol to get it to move?

Thanks, R.

Comment: Ok, typical, still don't know how to move it dynamically but I have my problem by setting the horizontalalignment property to right.  Thought there might be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Canvas as a container to hold the TabControl?  Canvas only supports absolute positioning, so you can position it using `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`.  If you need to stretch the control to fill the area, you can bind to the ActualWidth/ActualHeight of the Canvas container.

Here's an example of what the XAML might look like.

```
        <Canvas x:Name="tabCanvas" Grid.Row="1">
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=tabCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=tabCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <TabItem Header="Item 1" />
            <TabItem Header="Item 2" />
        </TabControl>
    </Canvas>
```